# 1996 Chevy G10 - Where Does "Hard" Vacuum Line Go?

Tags: chevrolet, vacuum, g10-van

I was attempting to replace the vacuum check valve in my 96 Chevy G10 with 5.0 V8 and approximately 144,xxx miles. The check valve has three fittings, the two opposite each other were "soft" 7/32" lines; the "other" one was a harder, thinner line ([for reference, this is the part I used](http://www.autozone.com/emission-control-and-exhaust/check-valve-universal-type/help-check-valve-universal-type/230927_0_0)).

Unfortunately, this hard line ended up being pulled and disconnected at the other end (the one not attached to check valve). One of the other two lines goes around the PCV area, and the other goes to the large black half-sphere "thing", located under the battery, near the front of the vehicle. However, I cannot figure out where the line that got disconnected goes.

The [vacuum diagram for the van](http://repairguide.autozone.com/znetrgs/repair_guide_content/en_us/images/0900c152/80/06/c6/2f/large/0900c1528006c62f.gif) (from AutoZone's website) was, unfortunately, not helpful for me.

Any advise is appreciated.

EDIT:

Picture of "hard" line.
[image]

Comment: I'm pretty sure the hard line would be your vacuum source. Have you looked in the radiator support area of your van (under the hood)? There should be a vacuum line routing guide in there somewhere showing where different things should be routed. It will either go directly to a manifold port, or to a solenoid which will direct vacuum.

Comment: Thanks much. However, I am curious if this would still be true given that one of the other two lines (which are properly connected) goes to the intake manifold; that is, would not that line be the vacuum source/supply? I am certainly not an expert, just trying to clarify. Thanks again.